# PyroCMS CKEditor Formatted Text Type Issues

Tags: codeigniter, ckeditor, pyrocms

PyroCMS v2.1

New lines / white space is added in the wysiwyg (ckeditor) when the 'formatted' text type is chosen.  Is there a way to get around this?

Expected code looks like this:

```
class person {
    public $name;
    function __construct($persons_name) {
            $this->name = $persons_name;
    }

    function set_name($new_name) {
            $this->name = $new_name;
    }

    function get_name() {
            return $this->name;
   }

}
```

But ends up looking like this:

```
class person {

    public $name;

    function __construct($persons_name) {

            $this->name = $persons_name;

    }


    function set_name($new_name) {

            $this->name = $new_name;

    }


    function get_name() {

            return $this->name;

   }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug with CKEditor 3.4.2 & fixed in 3.5.1:

Bug case:
http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/6630

Fix:
http://dev.ckeditor.com/changeset/6321